# The server starts, but the page does not open in the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

I start the server through the terminal, it says that the server started successfully, but the page does not open in the browser.
code:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoode = require('mongoose');
const router = require('./router/index');
const { default: mongoose } = require('mongoose');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors());
app.use('/api', router);

const start = async () => {
try {
await mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URL, {
useNewUrlParser: true,
useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server startding ${PORT}`));

} catch (e) {
console.log(e);
}
};
start();
```

the error is displayed in the browser:
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

I tried changing the code and browser but unfortunately nothing helped.